# How does one recursively count the maximum nesting occurrence of a specific, itself repeating, sub data structure which is an array of object items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, data-structures

Hi i get object with my backend, looks like that:

```
 reaction {[
          some data about reaction ,
          reactions: {[
                     some data about reaction ,
                     reactions: {[
                                 some data about comment,
                                 reactions: 
                                ]}
                    ]}
          ]}
```

Nested reactions can be infinity, and there can be any number of reactions in the reaction.

I try count all reactions:

```
reaction.flat(Infinity).length
```

also i try:

```
const getArrayDepth = arr => {
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
      return 1 + Math.max(...arr.map(getArrayDepth));
    }
    if (arr.reactions&& arr.reactions.length) {
      return 1 + Math.max(...arr.reactions.map(getArrayDepth));
    }
    return 0;
  };
```

and

```
const totalReactions  = arr => arr.reduce((count, current) => count + current.reactions.length, 0);
```

but I get an incorrect number, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful?

Comment: The OP's source data structure apparently is broken. The OP might think about either fixing it or providing it as less error prone example code to the audience.

Comment: @PeterSeliger That's a bit extreme. Recursive data structures are common in many algorithms. For instance, a data structure that represents a filesystem can be nested as deep as the directories.

Comment: The DOM hierarchy is another example -- you can have DIVs nested in DIVs arbitrarily deeply.

Comment: @Barmar ... which means that `reaction {[ some data about reaction , reactions: {[ ...` 
 for you is not featuring a broken syntax?

Comment: I don't think "some data about reaction" was intended to be literal syntax, it's a placeholder.

Comment: @PeterSeliger It's just a view, not what the data looks like. On the backend, I retrieve the list of all reactions from the database recursively and I want to count on the frontend how many nested reactions

Comment: I have more than 30 fields, but I am only interested in one field, nested reactions.
I don't think what id, date of creation, author, etc. you are interested in

Comment: Since your data is recursive, why not use a recursive function to count?

Comment: @tromgy Now I am learning javascript and try to use all the possibilities of the language, I can write a simple recursive function, but I'm afraid that it will be bad because I do not use possible js. Unfortunately, the only way to ask more experienced people is stackoverflow

Comment: @kiker ... The reason I might look like a nitpicking pedant is that the OP asks for ... *"I try count all comments"* ... and the pseudo data structure also features something like ... `some data about comment,` ... but the provided approach does not take anything `comment` related into account. Thus the OP might please get more precise with both the question and the code. A boiled down but reliable example code will do it.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Excuse me, I wrote the question a little earlier but did not publish it, then I changed the names in my project, but did not change everything in the question.

Comment: @kiker ... There is another thing which doesn't make any sense or has to be considered badly designed. One does either nest arrays and objects in a meaningful altering way, or one does nest pure objects (here with a repeating structure) only, or one does so with just arrays. There is no good reason to (ab/mis)use an array as object by nailing another property like `reactions` to it like the OP is doing/expecting with e.g ... `arr.reactions.map`. Thus questioning the OP's pseudo code with the 1st comment seems even more legitimate. OP, be precise. Provide the code you are really working with.

Comment: @PeterSeliger What I am doing does not make sense either, because I am making a copy of stackoverflow with my features, programming is my hobby, not work

Comment: @PeterSeliger At first I only had comments, but then I added likes / dislikes and renamed them in reaction.
I receive a post (a question like on stackoverflow) and inside there are reactions, i.e. comments and likes / dislikes. They are stored as an example, why is that? I store responses to comments and reactions to them in an array, you can reply to each comment and like / dislike and they fall into the array of the current comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getMaximumReactionsFoldCount(reactions, foldCount = 0) {
  return reactions.reduce((count, item) => {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('reactions')) {

      count = Math.max(
        count,
        getMaximumReactionsFoldCount(item.reactions, ++foldCount)
      );
    }
    return count;

  }, foldCount);
}

const reactions = [{              // 1
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  reactions: [{                   // 1a-2
    fooBar: 'foo-bar',
    bazBiz: 'bar-biz',
    reactions: [{                 // 1a-2-3
      foo: 'foo',
      bar: 'bar',
      reactions: [{               // 1a-2-3-4
        // ... more ...
      }],
    }],
    buzBoz: 'buz-boz',
  }],
  baz: 'baz',
}, {
  fooFoo: 'foo-foo',
  barBar: 'bar-bar',
  reactions: [{                   // 1b-2
    fooBarBaz: 'foo-bar-baz',
    reactions: [{                 // 1b-2-3
      foo: 'foo',
      bar: 'bar',
      reactions: [{               // 1b-2-3-4a
        fooBar: 'foo-bar',
        bazBiz: 'bar-biz',
        reactions: [{             // 1b-2-3-4a-5
          foo: 'foo',
          bar: 'bar',
          reactions: [{           // 1b-2-3-4a-5-6
            reactions: [{         // 1b-2-3-4a-5-6-7
              reactions: [{       // 1b-2-3-4a-5-6-7-8
                // ... more ...
              }],
              bizzz: 'BIZZZ',
            }],
            buzzz: 'BUZZZ',
          }],
          bozzz: 'BOZZZ',
        }],
        buzBoz: 'buz-boz',
      }],
      baz: 'baz',
    }, {
      fooFoo: 'foo-foo',
      barBar: 'bar-bar',
      reactions: [{               // 1b-2-3-4b
        fooBarBaz: 'foo-bar-baz',
        reactions: [              // 1b-2-3-4b-5
          // ... more ...
        ],
        bizBuzBoz: 'biz-buz-boz',
      }],
      bazBaz: 'baz-baz',
    }],
    bizBuzBoz: 'biz-buz-boz',
  }],
  bazBaz: 'baz-baz',
}];

console.log(
  'getMaximumReactionsFoldCount(reactions) ...',
  getMaximumReactionsFoldCount(reactions)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @kiker ... You 're welcome. And I had to make a sophisticated guess about how your data might be structured in a meaningful/usable way. Looks like a match now.